# How to Display Page Number for iFrame Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, pagination

I have main page that includes iframe and pagination.

I want to display the page numbers of the iframe pages on the sidebar of **main page** (means, not in the iframe itself but in the page that contain the iframe)

Here is image that display what exactly i want it do:

[image]

I use that jquery code (Using jquery-1.9.1.js):

```
    <script>
  var locations = ["./pages/0.html","./pages/1.html", "./pages/2.html", "./pages/3.html","./pages/4.html"];
  var currentIndex = 0;
  var len = locations.length;
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':button').click(function() {
        currentIndex = this.value == "Next" ? 
                currentIndex < len - 1 ? ++currentIndex : len - 1 : 
                currentIndex > 0 ? --currentIndex : 0;
        $('#zoome').attr('src', locations[currentIndex]);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I wonder what is the correct code to display the page numbers **between** the next and previous buttons?

Here is a live link: [**Coreneto**](http://coreneto.com/delete/Test/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can us this code to get the html

```
$('#iframe').load(function() {
    var src = $('#iframe').contents().find("html").html();
    alert(src);
});
```

You can also use this to get an element's specific value.
You did not say where the pagination value is located but I assume it's in a div or something.

To get specific value

```
$('input:button[name=ButtonName]').click(function() {
    var name = $('iframe[name=IframeName]').contents().find('#ControlId').val();
});
```

EDIT--------------------------------
Because you have provided more information, this is my suggestion.

Create a counter label and place it in between the next and previous button.
With javascript increment the label amount when you click next and decrease when going previous.
Make a save guard that you have a min and max to back and forward with. This prevents on being on page -1 or a higher number than pages you are navigating to.

Comment: That is hard to say since we don't know the element where the page number is. If you gave a URL of the website or the name of the item that holds the page number than we can help you

Comment: You can see the system here: http://coreneto.com/delete/Test/index.html